# CLR/System.EntryPointNotFoundException при запуске неуправляемого кода на Си из программы на C# в среде Linux

Tags: c#, c, gcc, .net-core

Код на Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

Команда сборки этого кода в модуль main.dll для Терминала Linux:

```
gcc main.c -o main.dll
```

Вызывающий код на C# (сборка dllimportc.dll):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
namespace netcore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            main();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        [DllImport("main.dll", EntryPoint = "main", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void main ();
    }
}
```

На вызове main(); возникает исключение:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.EntryPointNotFoundExceptionAn unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in dllimportc.dll: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'main' in shared library 'main.dll'.'
>   at dllimportc.Program.main()
>   at dllimportc.Program.Main()

Как откорректировать программу, чтобы .Net Core в консольном приложении находил точку входа и Hello World выводился два раза без исключений?

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**
В коде выше библиотека в Linux создавалась неправильно. Правильные инструкции можно подсмотреть здесь - [Создание библиотеки в Linux](https://rtfm.co.ua/c-sozdanie-i-primenenie-shared-library-v-linux/).
Для Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  пришлось добавить возвращаемый тип в функцию на Си и вместо команды

> ldconfig -v -n .

использовать

> ldconfig -v -n -l main.so.0.0

**ОБНОВЛЕНО 06.10.2018**

Можно проще: использовать для сборки только команду

> gcc -o main.so -s -shared -O2 main.c -m64

Затем подкладываем main.so в bin, и в C# для .Net Core всё просто:

```
 [DllImport("main.so")]
  public static extern void main ();
```

Comment: Лучше оформите ответом то, что вы добавили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подключения через extern внешний код должен быть собран как библиотека.
Для этого можно в Linux использовать для сборки команду (предварительно должен быть установлен компилятор GCC, если его не было в системе):

> gcc -o main.so -s -shared -O2 main.c -m64

Для библиотеки наличие функции main не обязательно. Исходный файл на чистом Си main.c эта команда скомпилирует в библиотеку (за это отвечает флаг shared) main.so (в Linux рекомендуется называть библиотеки с префиксом lib и давать им расширение so). Флаги s и O2 отвечают за оптимизацию для продуктива, а флаг m64 настраивает принудительную сборку для платформы x64. Затем подкладываем main.so в подпапку папки bin, где лежит собранный файл вашего проекта, и в C# для .Net Core всё просто:

```
  [DllImport("main.so")]
  public static extern void main ();
```

Чтобы увидеть текстовое сообщение из внешней библиотеки,  можно собрать проект .Net Core как консольное приложение, сделать вызов main() как обычного метода C# в теле вашей программы и запустить собранный проект из Терминала.