# Как передать структуру как параметр функции из программы на C# в программу на C и вернуть структуру обратно?

Tags: c#, c, interop

Как с помощью вызова extern функции библиотеки на чистом Си из языка C# передать в неё struct со значениями и получить в возвращаемом значении тот же struct?

Функция и структура в C#:

```
public struct Structure 
{ 
    public int a; 
    public char c; 
    public string s; 
    public double d; 
    public float f; 
}

[DllImport("lib")]
public static extern Structure entry (Structure s);
```

Вызов в коде C#:

```
var s = entry(
              new Structure 
                  { 
                       a = 1,
                       c = 'c',
                       f = 2,
                       d = 3,
                       s = "abc"
                  }
              );
```

выдаёт исключение при обращении к методу entry:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AccessViolationException
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Код библиотеки lib на Си:

```
struct Structure 
{
    int a;
    char c;
    float f;
    double d;
    char * s; 
};

struct Structure entry(struct Structure x);

struct Structure entry(struct Structure x)
{
    struct Structure r = x;

    return r;
}

void main()
{    
}
```

Команда сборки библиотеки:

> gcc -o lib -s -shared -Ofast lib.c -m64

Подкладываю файл lib в */bin/Debug/net5.0/* и запускаю метод C#.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО 20.09.2021**

Код библиотеки lib.c:

```
   #include <uchar.h>

   struct Structure 
   {
       int a;
       char c;
       float f;
       double d;
       int * m;
       char16_t * s; 
   };

   struct Structure entry(struct Structure x);

   struct Structure entry(struct Structure x)
   {
       struct Structure r = x;
       short unsigned int t[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
       int t1[2] = {1,0};
       r.s=(short unsigned int *)t;
       r.m = (int*)t1;
       return r;
   }

   void main()
   {    
   }
```

Код C#:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct Structure
        {
            public int a;
            public char c;

            public double d;
            public float f;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
            public int[] m;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
            public string s;
        }

        [DllImport("lib")]
        public static extern Structure entry(Structure s);
```

Код вызова C#:

```
var s = entry(new Structure { a = 1, c = 'c', f = 2, d = 3, m = new int[] { 5, 7 }, s = "UTF-16" });
```

Некорректный результат:

> s.m[0] = 5;
> s.m[1] = случайный результат;
> s.s = случайный результат.

Comment: Покажите сигнатуру функции и определение этой структуры.

Comment: Вы этот код пробовали запустить и проверить? Вдруг работает? Не работает? Как вы это поняли? Как отлаживали? Выровняйте код в посте, трудно читать.

Comment: я C не знаю, но по-моему в начале объявления метода ключевое слово extern должно быть, а у вас какое-то struct

Comment: Должно без extern работать. Тут пишу о примере работы с библиотекой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887002/clr-system-entrypointnotfoundexception-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7

Comment: Пример передачи структуры в Си https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-passing-struct-to-function/ Если убрать `string s;`, `char * s;` в объявлениях и передачу соответствующих параметров, то работает.Похоже, класс никак не передать.

Comment: Давайте уточним: а) имеется код на C и нужно вызвать его из C#, б) имеется код на C# и нужно подогнать под него код C.

Comment: [Customize structure marshaling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/customize-struct-marshaling)

Comment: char в c - 8 бит, char в c# - 16 бит. Ну и да, строку нужно рассматривать особо. Что с ней будет сделано? Нужно изменить, вернуть копию или ссылку на ту же строку?

Comment: Предполагается, что все значения полей структуры в Си-коде будут изменены.

Comment: Подогнать код Си под вызов C#.

Comment: Есть какие-то подвижки? Делитесь наработками.

Comment: Удалось запустить, но с неверным результатом.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять charset (в C# коде) на ANSI, и установите в структуре на си `char s[6]`

Comment: Не помогло. Возвращает какой-то мусор.

Comment: `double d` и `float f` также поменяйте местами или в c#, или в си

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После комментариев коллег публикую полный ответ. Код проверялся в Linux x64 и .NET 5.
Упрощённая команда сборки библиотеки:

> gcc -o lib -s -shared lib.c

**ВАРИАНТ 1**

Код lib.c

```
#include <string.h>

struct Structure 
{
    int a;
    char c;
    double d;
    float f;
    int m[2];
    char s[6]; 
};

void entry(struct Structure* x);

void entry(struct Structure* x)
{
    memcpy(x->m, (int[2]){1, 2}, sizeof x->m);
    strncpy(x->s,"abcde\0",6);
}

void main()
{    
}
```

Код объявления C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Structure
{
    public int a;
    public char c;
    public double d;
    public float f;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] m;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string s;
}

[DllImport("lib")]
public static extern void entry([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In, Out] ref Structure s);
```

Код вызова C#

```
var parameter = new Structure  {   a = 1, c = 'c', f = 2, d = 3, m = new int[]  {  5, 7  } , s = "UTF-1\0"  };
entry(ref parameter);
```

**ВАРИАНТ 2**

Код lib.c

```
#include <uchar.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Structure 
{
    int a;
    char c;
    double d;
    float f;
    int m[2];
    char16_t s[6]; 
};

struct Structure entry(struct Structure x);

struct Structure entry(struct Structure x)
{
    char16_t string[6] = u"abcdef";
    memcpy(x.s, string, sizeof(string));
    
    return x;
}

void main()
{    
}
```

Код объявлений C#

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct Structure
        {
            public int a;
            public char c;    
            public double d;
            public float f;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = 2)]
            public int[] m;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
            public string s;
        }

        [DllImport("lib")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public static extern Structure entry([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In] Structure s);
```

Код вызова C#

```
Structure structure = entry(new Structure { a = 1, c = 'c', f = 2, d = 3, m = new int[2] { 5, 7 }, s = "UTF-16" });
```

Интересно, что строку меньшей длины из программы на Си возвращать можно, а большей, чем SizeConst, не получится - будет обрезана.

Comment: Если вы хотите не ограничивать длину строки, попробуйте для строки на C# указать атрибут `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450756/6468198 - судя по данному источнику, это должно сработать

Comment: Замена атрибута над строкой в структуре C# приводит к `An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'`

Comment: Во втором варианте в коде Си вместо `char c` должно быть `char16_t c`?

Comment: Да, это для двубайтного символа новинка стандарта Си.